# WebDriverWait is not working in Java script , How it use?

Tags: jmeter

I used JMeter. Try to automate one site using JavaScript.

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait)
var wait = new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000)
WDS.browser.get('http://mobile.yellow.com.au')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

When execute then got the below error. How it is resolved? and also please let me know how implicit /explicit wait is used to locate all elements and not thows org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException .

Error --> `javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Can not create new object with constructor org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait with the passed arguments; they do not match any of its method signatures. in <eval> at line number 3`

(Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:19:58.91Z')

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example from [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered) article:

```
var pkg = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium)
var support_ui = JavaImporter(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait)
var conditions = org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions
var wait=new support_ui.WebDriverWait(WDS.browser, 5000)

WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://example.com')
wait.until(conditions.presenceOfElementLocated(pkg.By.linkText('More finformation...')))
var element=WDS.browser.findElement(pkg.By.linkText("More information..."))
element.click()
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

and official documentation on [WebDriver Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)

Your `how implicit /explicit wait is used to locate all elements and not thows org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException` stanza doesn't make any sense, you should either use explicit wait to "wait" for a specific element to appear/disappear/become clickable/whatever or just go for implicit wait so WebDriver will automatically will "wait" for the element for specified amount of time before failing.

"All elements" is not something you can get using selectors, you can have list of locators and verify their presence at the page but not more.

Comment: I have already try for above code .. but again got same error-->Javax.script.ScriptException: TypeError: Can not create new object with constructor org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait with the passed arguments; they do not match any of its method signatures. in <eval> at line number 4

Comment: How did you install Selenium java libraries? The instructions apply to the WebDriver Sampler 3.3 installed via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager) and the error you're getting might indicate a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell), i.e. you're having different or multiple selenium libraries in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)